# QResource register multiple resources, resource loading principle, which is the last available resource?

Tags: qt, rcc, qresource, qt-resource

Let's say I have **3 qrc files**. The first **2 contain the same resource path** and the **3rd one doesn't contain that path**, for eg:

qrc1:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>res/image.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

qrc2:

```
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/">
    <file>res/image.png</file>
</qresource>
```

qrc3:

```
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/">
</qresource>
```

Loading the resources is done as follows:

```
QResource::registerResource("qrc1.rcc");
QResource::registerResource("qrc2.rcc");
QResource::registerResource("qrc3.rcc");
```

so the **rcc** files are **registered in the above order**. So when someone tries to get `qrc:/res/image.png`, which file it will get? from the first rcc that contains the respective resource(from qrc1) or from the last successfully loaded rcc (from qrc2)? I couldn't find an answer in the docs.

My tests show that it takes the resource from the first successful loaded rcc, even though I was expecting to get it from the last rcc. What should I do in order to take the resource from the last successful loaded rcc? Any ideas? Did somebody understand the **resource loading principle in terms of order**? Thanks.